# Deleting rows by batches. How to open / reuse SQL Server connection?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

What would be the most effective way to open/use a SQL Server connection if we're reading rows to be deleted in batches?

```
foreach(IEnumerable<Log> logsPage in LogsPages)
{
    foreach(Log logEntry in logsPage)
    {
        // 1. get associated filenames
        // 2. delete row
        // 3. try delete each file
    }
}
```

- Log page size is about 5000 rows
- Files associated with the log entries may vary in size. I don't think they are larger than say 500 Mb.
- We use Dapper

Should we let Dapper open connections on each step of the `foreach` loop? I suppose SQL Server connection pooling takes place here?

Or should we open an explicit connection per batch?

Comment: Why not read all files in a single step, then execute a single `DELETE` to delete all of them based on the same criteria you used for `SELECT`? You could execute that command concurrently with the file deletion operations. To avoid ghost files if the file operation fails while the Db succeeds you could store the file list to disk and restart deletions after a failure

Comment: You could run deletions concurrently, up to a point. File operations aren't pure IO, as the OS performs its own house keeping, and data is cached at multiple levels, from the OS down to the disk itself. You may be able to reduce the deletion time by deleting files concurrently with a limited DOP, eg using an ActionBlock with a DOP>1

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Do you mean querying all filenames per batch and then trying to drop them [files] in parallel with rows deletion? I've never used TPL DataFlow before, something to wrap my head around.

Comment: use `SELECT Filename  from sometable  where ...` to get the filenames, store the list, then use `DELETE sometable where ....` or `delete sometable FROM sometable INNER JOIN ...` using the same conditions as the select query. While that takes place you can delete the files from the list using `File.Delete`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're performing multiple database operations in a tight loop, it would usually be preferable to open the connection for the duration of all the operations. Returning the connection to the pool can be beneficial in contested systems where there can be an *indeterminate* interval before the next database operation, but if you're doing lots of sequential operations: constantly fetching and returning connections from the pool (and executing `sp_reset_connection`, which happens behind the scenes) add overhead for no good reason.

So to be explicit, I'd have the `Open[Async]()` here above the *first* `foreach`.

Note: for batching, you might find that there are ways of doing this with fewer round-trips, in particular making use of the `IN` re-writing in Dapper based on the ids. Since you mention SQL-Server, This can be combined with setting a `SqlMapper.Settings.InListStringSplitCount` to something positive (5, 10, etc are reasonable choices; note that this is a global setting); for example, for a *simple* scenario:

```cs
connection.Execute("delete from Foo where Id in @ids",
    new { ids = rows.Select(x => x.Id) });
```

is *much* more efficient than:

```cs
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    connection.Execute("delete from Foo where Id = @id",
        new { id = row.Id });
}
```

---

Without `InListStringSplitCount`, the first version will be re-written as something like:

```sql
delete from Foo where Id in (@ids0, @ids1, @ids2, ..., @idsN)
```

With  `InListStringSplitCount`, the first version will be re-written as something like:

```sql
delete from Foo where Id in (select cast([value] as int) from string_split(@ids,','))
```

which allows the exact same query to be used many times, which is good for query-plan re-use.